# Не получается добавить Scene в Stage в режиме реального времени

Tags: javafx, firestore

Я хочу создать программу в JavaFX, которая открывается с помощью телефона. Я уже написал Android приложение. И она отправляет в Firebase данные. В проекте Maven я тоже добавил Firebase и SnapshotListener успешно работает. Только вот если я попытаюсь внутри SnapshotListener создать окно, программа зависает, но продолжает работать. Не выводит никакие ошибки и меня это вводит в ступор. Я много искал но так  и не нашел ничего.

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) {
    //Подключаемся к проекту Firebase
    new ConnectionFirebase();

    //Подключаем Firestore
    Firestore firestore = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

    firestore.collection("Go").document("view").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirestoreException e) {
            if (documentSnapshot != null){
                System.out.println("SnapshotListener on");
                new PlayVideo(stage);
            }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

ConnectionFirebase class:

```
public class ConnectionFirebase {
public ConnectionFirebase(){
    InputStream serviceAccount = null;
    try {
        serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("src/files/playvideo-d3ae8-firebase-adminsdk-o4crm-a0bb32af45.json");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GoogleCredentials credentials = null;
    try {
        credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://playvideo-d3ae8.firebaseio.com")
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

}
```

PlayVideo class:

```
public class PlayVideo {
    public PlayVideo(Stage stage){
         System.out.println("Run PlayVideo...");
         Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 640, 360);
         stage.setScene(scene);
         System.out.println("Running...");

         stage.setTitle("Believer");
         stage.show();
    }
}
```

По заметкам понял что не работает именно метод stage.setScene(scene);
Я попробовал создать это не внутри SnapshotListener и это было удачно. Окно открылся.

Comment: Никогда не делал FX для телефона. Firebase наверняка работает в своем потоке и в `onEvent` приходит не fx поток, это не объясняет отсутствие ошибки конечно. Вы пробовали `PlayVideo(Stage stage)` обернуть в `Platform.runLater`?

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы помогли мне. Я сам начинающий программист и не знал что такое Platform.runLater. Я примерно догадывался что проблема в потоке, но не знал как это проверить и как это исправить.